# Getting the Authentication username column

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I need to get the auth username that is used by the app for authentication from a `User` object. The column used for authentication is changing based on system/environment (can be `email` or `username` or some other column)

Is it a good idea to put that as a public property in the `User` model (I will add `username_column` to `auth.php`):

```
class User extends Authenticatable 
{
    public $username_column = config('auth.username_column')
}
```

or as a getter in the `User` model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable 
{
    public function getUsernameColumn()
    {
        return config('auth.username_column');
    }
}
```

Or something else?

Edit: For more context, I get the `User` object in a `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` event's Listener:

```
public function handle(Object $event)
{
    // $user = $event->user
}
```

and I want to get the value of the column that is used by the app to authenticate the user (and it can change - sometimes `username`, sometimes `email`, and sometimes other custom column)

Comment: can you add more context or an example ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? the column name or the value of the column?

Comment: @xenooooo added at the bottom of the post an example. Rigsto I need the value eventually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you shouldn't put your column name in the configuration. An authentication identifier isn't something that we change regularly, so don't put the identifier in the public property. Laravel Authenticatable has provided some methods to implement your custom column.

On the controller that handles the authentication or login process, inside the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, there is a method named `username()` as the column name that will be used for the `Auth::attempt()` process

```php
public class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username_column'
    }
}
```

When the user has been authenticated, 2 options can be used:

**Option 1**: 
We can override the Authenticatable trait to get the identifier and the value.

- `getAuthIdentifierName()` will return the name of the username column
- `getAuthIdentifier()` will return the value of the username column

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return `username_column`
    }
}

/* Get the Auth username */
Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier();
```

**Option 2**: 
You can call using the `Auth` identifier without overriding the authenticable methods.

```php
User::find(Auth::id())->username_column;
```

More information:

- [Authenticatable](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/Authenticatable.html)

Comment: `getAuthIdentifier()` and `getAuthIdentifierName()` return the unique identifier of the DB table, not the column that is used to authenticate the user with the `username()` method in the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait. So they return the `id` column and its value respectively

Comment: Sorry @B.D Liroy, I forgot that the default of `getAuthIdentifierName()` is the primary key of the model. I've updated the code.